# HTML tel: link for private calls

Tags: html, ios, mobile, web, tel

Trying to find out if there is a way to keep the callers number private when the user touches a tel link on a mobile webpage. We tried prefixing the phone number with *67, however, apple's iOS prevents the call when the number has * or #, as stated in their documentation. For example,

```
<a href="tel:*67215-555-5555">call</a>
```

Will look like a valid link, but won't make the call on the iPhone. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is few line of code to make a call inside mobile webpage.

```
<p>Making call from webpage.</p>
<a href='#' id='contact' tel:'+1800229933'>contact: 1800229933</a>
```

and if you want to see live, then brows this url in your mobile.
http://openstrides.com/mobile-openstrides-website/contact.html

here is a useful link for depth learning.
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers

Comment: Hey naresh, thanks for answering, but I think you're misunderstanding the question. The problem is that we want the user to be able to make the call from a PRIVATE number (It's a doctor calling a patient).  In order to do that in the US you can normally dial *67 before the number.  According to apple docs (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html): "if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number".  So is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: ok. I got it. I do not have much technical knowledge about this topic. I share with you a link in my previous comment, right. You can ask this question to them. They are expert, may be they will help.